# How to style an unordered list with jQuery UI so that the elements begin with a UI icon instead of the default list symbol?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, icons

I would like to use an icon from the [jQuery UI icon set](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) to style an unordered list.

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>John Doe</li>
        <li>Jack Snow</li>
        <li>Mary Moe</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**By default this list appears with dots in front of each element**:

- John Doe
- Jack Snow
- Mary Moe

**Instead I would like to replace the dot with an icon** such as **`ui-icon-person`**

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is a little out-of-date - but here is a fully working example:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <ul class="icon person">
    <li>John Doe</li>
    <li>Jack Snow</li>
    <li>Mary Moe</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul.icon {
    list-style: none; /* This removes the default bullets */
    padding-left: 20px; /* This provides proper indentation for your icons */
}
ul.icon li { 
    position: relative; /* Allows you to absolutely place the :before element
                           relative to the <li>'s bounding box. */
}
ul.icon.person li:before {
    background: url(/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png) -144px -96px;
   /* ex: download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png */
   /* The -144px, -96px coordinate is the location of the 16x16 Person icon */

    /* The next 2 lines are necessary in order to make the :before pseudo-element
       appear, and thereby show it's background, your icon. */
    content: ''; 
    display: inline-block;

    /* Absolute is always in relation to the nearest positioned parent. In this
       case, that's the <li> with _relative_ positioning, above. */
    position: absolute;

    left: -16px; /* Places the icon 16px left of the <li>'s edge */
    top: 2px;    /* Adjust this based on your font-size and line-height */

    height: 16px; width: 16px; /* jQuery UI icons (with spacing) are 16x16 */
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle showing it working](http://jsfiddle.net/TroyAlford/56xUw/). The result will look something like this:

[image: Example Image]

The reason that I used the `:before` pseudo-element is that you are wanting to use jQuery-UI icons - which come in the form of a sprite map. In other words - all of the icons are found in a grid pattern within a single image, as in this example:

Source: http://download.jqueryui.com/themeroller/images/ui-icons_888888_256x240.png

[image: jQuery UI Icons]

If you tried to just make the background of the `<li>` that image, it would be more complicated to make the single icon that you want appear without also displaying all of its neighbors. By using the `:before` element, though, you can create a smaller, `16px` by `16px` box for the icon, and thereby easily trim down to showing only one icon.

If you want to learn more about `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, check out [this fantastic article](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/) as a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source for the page, just set the class file of the list item to clear the standard element, and then set a span tag to add the new icon.

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
  <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-person"></span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    background: url('your/path/image.png') no-repeat left center; 
}
```

You may need to add some left padding as well.