# Using jQuery UI icons as <li> backgrounds

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I would like to replace the regular html list item dot with an image from [the jQuery UI icon sheet](http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/jqueryui-icons/):

**CSS:**

```
li { padding: 0 0 0 5px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="ui-icon ui-icon-play">abc</li>
    <li>abc</li>
</ul>
```

I don't see my text when I add the image class. What did I miss here?

http://jsfiddle.net/KKhZg/509/

Comment: Do the suggestions here work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419950/how-to-style-an-unordered-list-with-jquery-ui-so-that-the-elements-begin-with-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add class to `li.ui-icon` it is going to get the width of `ui-icon` which is defined `16px`.

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/KKhZg/510/).

Answer (score 2):

As seemly said, you can insert a nested element inside the `li`.

If you don't want to do that, just add these two rules to `li`:

```
li {
    text-indent: 16px !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KKhZg/512/

`16px` is the width of all jquery ui icons, so I guess you want your text indented after the icon.

I have put `!important` because it seems that on jsfiddle, the jqueryUI is loaded after the user css, otherwise the `text-indent` and `overflow` would get overriden by the `.ui-icon`

Answer (score 1):

That will be due to the text-indent on that class name. You may need to insert a nested element (maybe a span), and apply the icon class on that element instead.